# Pausing game in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have a little problem in Sprite Kit for iOS 7.
What I want to do is simply pause my game. The problem is that I can't use either the *`self.paused`* or the *`self.view.paused`* property because after pausing the game, I want to put several buttons on the screen (resume, quit etc.) and those need to have animations on them (which is not possible if either the scene or the view is paused).

I tried the following:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"*" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    node.paused = YES;
}];
[self physicsWorld].speed = 0.0;
```

... Which pauses the game perfectly, and it can be reverted quite easily (I won't paste that code in, it's pretty self-explanetory). This way the game is perfectly frozen, and I can still put some buttons up with animations. Good.

The only problem is that when I send the app to the background (via pushing the home button) and then bring it back, the game is not paused (even though I call the code above every time the app is sent to the background). **Somehow it seems to me that the nodes are "forgetting" that their *`paused`* property was set to *`YES`* if the app goes into the background.** I tried *`NSLog`* ing out the *`paused`* property of the nodes and this is what I get:

0 when the game is running

1 when the app is sent to the background (because the code I pasted sets it to 1)

0 when the app comes back (???)

I tried calling *`[self pauseGame]`* (my own method which has the code I pasted earlier) when the app is activated again (from *`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`*) but it didn't help. Interesting... even calling the pause method after the app becomes active doesn't pause the game, it leaves it running.

If anyone knows something, I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: You can try adding `node.speed = 0.0;` in enumerateChildNodesWithName

Comment: Okay, I give that a try

Comment: It works :) and this way I don't even need the *`node.paused`* thing. Thanks dude. Add it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"*" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    node.paused = YES;
}];
```

To this:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"*" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    node.speed = 0.0;
}];
```

By setting the speed to 0 you are ensuring that even if the node's actions are being processed, nothing will occur. For some reason, `node.paused` wasn't causing SpriteKit to skip over those nodes when rendering the next frame when the app is sent to the background, so it didn't pause the game.

Comment: You _could_ opt to keep `node.paused` there in addition.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should for safety. That makes the game _very_ paused now haha. Thanks!